# "If...or..." statement inside list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

In Python 3.4.2, is there a way to have an "if ... or ..." statement in a list comprehension?

Example:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in other_list
                 if not '    ' in x or '    ' in other_list[int(other_list.index(x) -1)]]
                                                 #^item just before "x" in "other_list"
```

I know this command doesn't work. I know this one doesn't either:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in other_list
                 if not ('    ' in x) or ('    ' in other_list[int(other_list.index(x) -1)])]
                                                    #^item just before "x" in "other_list"
```

Is there a way to do this? A "for" loop would be way easier to read, but I'm trying to push my understanding of list comprehensions. Thanks in advance.

(Oddly enough, I can't find a previous question like this on stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code **does** do exactly what you're telling it to do (in simple cases):

```
>>> other_list = ['foo', 'bar    ', 'baz    ']
>>> filtered_list = [x for x in other_list
...                  if not '    ' in x or '    ' in other_list[int(other_list.index(x) -1)]]
>>> print filtered_list
['foo', 'baz    ']
```

i.e, it picks all items that either don't contain four spaces, or follow an item that **does** contain four spaces.

It's really weird code in many ways -- for example, why use `.index` which will pick the **first** item equal to `x` in case of duplicates; and, should the first item be considered to "follow" the last one as this code is saying?  But, without a clear explanation in English of what your code is supposed to accomplish, just "reverse engineering" the code as written, it does appear to do exactly what it says in simple cases (first item does not contain four spaces, no duplicates), although very, **very** inefficiently (O(N squared) where it's trivially simple to make it O(N) with `enumerate`).

So please supply a clear, exhaustive explanation of **what** you think you're doing here, and I'll gladly edit this answer to show you how to do what you actually mean, rather than what you (apparently wrongly) **coded**.  But, I can't read your mind, so... (BTW, this does need to be "an answer" since formatting the code above is crucial to its readability, so it can't be "just a comment").

Added: the normal way to "get the item just before the current one in `other_list`" would of course **not** use `.index` (which is `O(N)` so makes the whole list comprehension `O(N squared)`!) but rather `enumerate`.  What is "the item just before" the **first** one requires interpretation, but the normal reading is "there is no such thing".

So suppose you have two functions `curp` (predicate qualifying the current item, if truthy on it) and `prevp` (predicate qualifying the current item, if truthy on the **previous** item **if any**).  Then, the normal way to pick items from list `xs` would clearly be:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(xs) if curp(x) or i>0 and prevp(xs[i-1])]
```

Of course it works exactly the same way whether the predicates are elegantly encapsulated into functions, as above, or more roughly expressed in-line.  So if, e.g:

```
def curp(x): return 'AB' not in x
def prevp(xp): return 'CD' in xp
```

then the following listcomp is equivalent to the previous one, just less readable:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(xs) if 'AB' not in X or i>0 and 'CD' in xs[i-1]]
```

Parentheses would be rather redundant here, and `not 'AB' in X` an even less elegant, readable, and unambiguous way to express `'AB' not in X` -- but, feel free to ignore these style opinions, they only come from 15 years' worth of Python experience, after all:-)

Comment: I think you're saying that I should add an answer to my question rather than adding a comment to your answer, so sure I'll do that.

Comment: Hey I didn't even think of using enumerate! Awesome idea

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple `and`s/`or`s but only one `if`. As an example, the following:

```
In [7]: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

In [8]: b = [x for x in a if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0]

In [9]: b
Out[9]: [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem:

```
other_list = ['foo', 'bar    ', 'baz    ']
filtered_list = [x for x in other_list if ('    ' not in x) or ('    ' not in other_list[int(other_list.index(x) -1)])]
print filtered_list
```

Note: the location of not determines how the command is interpreted. I thought you wanted something like this.

Comment: Nice! I would have never thought of that! I thought it might just be a little syntax mistake like that.

Comment: "the location of not determines how the command is interpreted": not it doesn't.  `not a in x or y` is always identical to `a not in x or y` and to `(a not in x) or y`.  Only very specific parenthesization like `a not in (x or y)` would change that.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes I just realized that I wrote my example wrong. I wanted to switch the if and for statements around:

```
filtered_list = [x
                 if not '    ' in x or '    ' in other_list[int(other_list.index(x) -1)]
                 for x in other_list]
```

I'll post my whole list comprehension to show why I want it in this order. Basically, I have a list with some indented items. For each of the indented items, I want to double its indent and indent the item before it, all while leaving the rest of the items in the list untouched.

```
indented_list = [t
                 if not '    ' in t or '    ' in stripped_list[int(stripped_list.index(t) + 1)]
                    else ''.join(('    ', t))
                    if not t[0].isdigit()
                        else re.sub(r'^(\d)(.*)', r'\1\2   \3',
                                    stripped_list[int(stripped_list.index(t))])
                        if not t[1].isdigit()
                            else re.sub(r'^(\d)(\d)(.*)', r'\1\2  \3',
                                        stripped_list[int(stripped_list.index(t))])
                 for t in stripped_list]
```

I know there's probably way easier ways to do this. I just started learning to program a few weeks ago.

Comment: Inside a LC, the order is **strictly**: **first** the `for` clause, mandatory, **then** the `if` clause, optional.  And, there's no `if/else` clause (one might use an `if/else` **expression** but that requires a value **before** the `if` keyword).  If you "just started learning to program a few weeks ago" you might be well advised to avoid list comprehensions for now, and stick with `for` loops, `if` statements (which **can** have an `else` clause if needed!-), and `.append` calls to build up new lists.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Also, that 'or i>0 and' in your answer was something else I was trying to figure out how to do too. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Always glad to be of help!